# Why isn't JQuery One Page Navigation ChangeHash value not working?

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I seem to be having an issue with my one page navigation website. When I push my keys down or even scroll down the links don't change. What am I doing wrong?There is a video that I posted about the issue I'm having.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yK_tjT536bA

Comment: For future reference, although a video gives a much clearer picture of what the problem is and your thought process, most people aren't going to bother watching it, so including a small amount of code is also pretty important. Just a tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have two choices looking at your existing code. You can either get this functionality using [bootstrap javascript](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy), or **[jquery.nav](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav), which is the one I think you're trying to use**. I'll give example usage for both, regardless.

## Bootstrap

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '#navbar-example' });
```

where `#navbar-example` is the ID or class of the parent element of any Bootstrap .nav component.

## Jquery.nav

```
$('#nav').onePageNav({
    changeHash: true,
    scrollSpeed: 750,
});
```

If you look at your code, your equivalent of this first line is incorrect (you have `$('#nav').onePageNav();`).

You also need to target the navbar `<li>` tag when the class `.current` is applied:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.current > a {
    color:#333;
}
```

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kmx460pg/4/). I made the navbar fixed using class `navbar-fixed-top` so it was more obvious.

Comment: @engima nice catch, however It's still not working. When I hold the up arrow key and down arrow key,It won't take effect.

Comment: @RawadMerhi aw, I was sure that was it. Does it work at all when you scroll using the scrollbar? If you let go of the arrow keys for a while after using them to scroll? Could do with some code to try out tbh...

Comment: No It's not working here is my css code:                                                 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
 color: #333;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active{
 color:#333;
}

Comment: @RawadMerhi can you chuck your code in here https://jsfiddle.net/, press save, and give me the link? I'll sort out the libraries and stuff

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76314/discussion-between-rawad-merhi-and-enigma).

Comment: I may need your help with one more issue I'm having It's going to be hard to explain by words so I'm going to make a quick video.